# Pynput- Running a while loop in both a keyboard and mouse listener

Tags: python, listener, python-multithreading, pynput

The point of the program is to detect when both the ctrl key and left mouse is held down. When I run it the `detect` function is still run even after I have released the ctrl key. It seems that `on_press` does not update the ctrl key's boolean value and `detect` will still run with only holding down left mouse button.

```
import threading
from pynput import mouse
from pynput import keyboard

mouse_running = False
keyboard_running = False

coordList = [(2, 3), (1, 7), (4, 8)]

def detected():
    while keyboard_running and mouse_running:
        for i in coordList:
            move_point = coordList[i]
            #move_point is now a tuple from the coordList. ex: (2, 3)
            pointer.move(move_point[0], move_point[1])


def on_click(x, y, button, pressed):
    global mouse_running
    if button == mouse.Button.left:
        if pressed:
            if not mouse_running:
                mouse_running = True
                threading.Thread(target=detected).start()
        else:
            mouse_running = False


def on_press(key):
    global keyboard_running
    if key == keyboard.Key.ctrl_l:
        if not keyboard_running:
            keyboard_running = True
            threading.Thread(target=detected).start()
    else:
        keyboard_running = False


Mouse_Listener = mouse.Listener(on_click=on_click)
Keyboard_Listener = keyboard.Listener(on_press=on_press)

Mouse_Listener.start()
Keyboard_Listener.start()
Keyboard_Listener.join()
Mouse_Listener.join()
```

The lmb will continue to run `detect` after one press of the ctrl key. Is there any way I can make `detect` run if both lmb and ctrl are held down.

Here's an annotated console result of the program. The left is the value of `keyboard_running` and the right is the value of `mouse_running`.

```
#ctrl pressed and released, left mouse pressed once
True True
False True
False True
False True
False True
False True
False True
#False True continues about 30 times.
```

Much appreciation

Comment: Looks like that you're using a busy loop to wait, that's not a good idea.

Comment: Besides, why are you having the `for i in range(30):` there?

Comment: @user202729 the `for i in range(30)` is to loop over a list of coordinates that I removed from the code to clean it up for the question. I still left the `for i in range(30)` in case it was the problem with the code. Is there another way to iterate over a list while both a mouse button and key held down?

Comment: Given that, it's observe that there will be about 30 lines without `True True` after you released one of them, right? But why is that a problem? What are you trying to do?

Comment: @user202729 I have a list of tuples that are coordinates. When both left mouse button and the ctrl key are held down I want the mouse to move to each coord. I used the for loop so that I can use `coordList[i]` to parse out the coordinate the mouse needs to go to.